# Alexa grantType 'authorization_code', pitangui redirect access token ok. Interaction phase do not start

Tags: web-services, token, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

i,m using local hook to handle Alex smarthome requests.
I.m following https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html
During grantType 'authorization_code', it redirects to pitangui and at token phase "expressApp.all('/faketoken'..  my server receives and answer ok the "access token" to Alexa service with the json obj answer:
"access_token":"Atza|EXAMPLEACCESSTOKEN123456...",
"token_type":"bearer",
"expires_in":3600,
"refresh_token":"Atzr|EXAMPLEREFRESHTOKEN123456X..."
however, the following phase do not goes through. Handler below do not receive the intent request from Alexa:
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
console.log("index.handler request  -----");
....
Also,  CloudWatch logs do not show any log.
I have enable the skill to use events.
Created function with Alexa trigger.

What could be missing here ?  Or Alexa SmartHome do not works with local hook at own server.

Thank you

Also, CloudWatch logs do not show any log.
I have enable the skill to use events.
Created function with Alexa trigger.

What could be missing here ?  Or Alexa SmartHome do not works with local hook at own server.

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate "with local hook at own server"? As long as your skill endpoint is on AWS Lambda, the lambda can communicate other servers or services and return results to Alexa from the skill endpoint. i.e. calling other lambda from skill endpoint lambda is possible. I believe account linking is not fully completed. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/authenticate-a-customer-permissions.html Can you make sure if your skill responds https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-authorization.html#acceptgrant-response-event